# Deleting FreePBX Speed Dials

Tags: asterisk, freepbx

Using freePBX 15.

From a phone, I entered *75 ( Asterisk Speed Dial entry "star code" )
and a speed dial label and code. This was just for a test.

Now, I want to delete it, but haven't found any way to do this.

I checked the Asterisk Phonebook for  my entry, but it wasn't there.

Comment: Why you need delete it? It not affect any operation and/or resources. Anyway, you have source code, just read it.

Comment: Same question created on two forums https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/629480/how-to-delete-a-speed-dial-in-asterisk-freepbx

Answer (score 0):

To delete speeddial you should manually remove asterisk database entry key AMPUSER/${AMPUSER}/speeddials/${entry}

Here is part of code which set it.

```
exten => s,n(success),Set(DB(AMPUSER/${AMPUSER}/speeddials/${newlocation})=${newnum})
```

No, you have no option for do that via dialplan, but you always welcome to make changed module.

For more info about database see this

https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+Internal+Database